How to permanently add a path in the user's `PATH`?
I'm creating an installer for one of my projects, which downloads the binaries of the project (in a ZIP file) and then unzips it into a directory in the programs folder of the OS, and I want to add this directory to the PATH.
My script is an installer with a UI, and it's aimed to be compiled to a .exe/executable.
I tried this:
import os

os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + install_dir # `install_dir` is the installation directory

But it's not permanent and doesn't stay at the end of the script.

This is something you typically set up in the shell/process that will execute your Python script, not the script itself. At best, you can edit a module or configuration file that your script will use.

@chepner Can you explain more?

For instance, maybe a shell configuration file includes PATH=/some/directory:$PATH, and when your Python script runs, the value of PATH already has the directory needed for whatever executable your script will run. It's not someone you configure at runtime, but at installation time.

@chepner My script is for downloading the binaries of my project and add the directory where the binaries are to the PATH.

I'm touchy about other programs touching my environment configuration. Inform me where the files are downloaded to (or better yet, let me tell the script where to install them after downloading), and I'll configure whatever environment needs to know where the binaries are.

My script download the ZIP containing the binaries in the temp folder of the system and then unzip it in C:/Progam Files/MyProject on Windows, /Applications/MyProject on macOS and /usr/local/bin/MyProject on Linux (using MyProject as the project name), and then delete the ZIP files from the temp folder.

Your script cannot affect the PATH variable of a process it does not itself create.  The best it can do is edit whatever configuration file is used to set PATH for a given process, and that is what I'm saying you shouldn't do. Let whoever needs to use the binaries configure their environment properly; it is enough for you to make them available.

I'm making an installer to make the installation process of the binaries more simple. It's like the Python installer for Windows (only to give an example, it's not really the same thing but it's the same intention).

Installers install; they do not configure other programs. Ideally, whoever needs the binaries decides where they should go, and the installer puts them where it is told. (I.e., you don't hard-code /usr/local/bin/MyProject, but let whoever runs your installer decide where MyProject should go.)

Why do you feel you need to change the PATH? In modern GUI-based OS's people run programs from icons/shortcuts which usually provide the full path to the exe. You would probably only need to add it the PATH if it is a command line tool. Is it?

@chepner This path is the default path for the installation, I'm working on a way to configure it, but that I want right now, in this question, is how to add the installation path to the system's PATH environment variable.

@001 It's a CLI tool.

You don't. There is no system PATH, at least not in UNIX. There are any number of ways any particular distribution might define a configuration file for process 1 from which any process might inherit a value of PATH, but typically PATH is initially defined more locally, by a login shell.

@chepner By "system PATH", I just meant the environment variable.

So do I. It is not standard for there to be a single value for PATH that is inherited by every processes.

I want the one that it at least used for the shell.

There is no platform-independent way to do that. On typical Linux distributions, you can probably get away with editing /etc/profile (which your installer should not do), while on macOS you would add an appropriate file under /etc/paths.d. Ultimately, the recommendation is to documetn where your installer will install a program, and the users of that program will ensure their PATH variable is updated appropriately.

So how does other installers do?

Many installation scripts end with a step that appends the command to the user's shell startup script. Or they provide a setup tool that users can use for this. Or they just put something in the documentation that tells users to do this by hand.

@Barmar Now I know, look at the answers you'll see that I made a script to add path to the PATH (and also remove them).

You're not supposed to change your question so that it invalidates existing answers. Should I delete mine now?

@tripleee
Excuse me, excuse me. I'm very sorry.

Here's what I did (I know, this isn't the best solution, but it works):
import os
import subprocess
import sys

def add_to_path_win(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('/', '\\').removesuffix("\\")

    key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(
        win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        r"Environment",
        0,
        win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS
    )

    current_path, _ = win32api.RegQueryValueEx(key, "Path")

    if new_path in current_path.split(os.pathsep) or \
       new_path + '\\' in current_path.split(os.pathsep):
        return

    new_path_value =  new_path + os.pathsep + current_path

    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "Path", 0, win32con.REG_EXPAND_SZ, new_path_value)
    win32api.RegCloseKey(key)

    refresh_path()

def edit_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path):
    with open(file_path, 'a') as environment_variables_file:
        environment_variables_file.write(f'PATH="{new_path}{os.pathsep}$PATH"\n')

    refresh_path()

def add_to_path_bash(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile')):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile')
    elif os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.profile')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .bash_profile/.profile")

    edit_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def add_to_path_sh(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.profile')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .profile")

    edit_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def add_to_path_zsh(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.expanduser('~/.zshenv'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.zshenv')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .zshenv")

    edit_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def add_to_path_unix(shell):
    if shell == 'bash':
        return add_to_path_bash
    elif shell == 'sh':
        return add_to_path_sh
    elif shell == 'zsh':
        return add_to_path_zsh
    
# ################################################################################

def remove_from_path_win(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('/', '\\').removesuffix("\\")

    key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(
        win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        r"Environment",
        0,
        win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS
    )

    current_path, _ = win32api.RegQueryValueEx(key, "Path")
    current_path = current_path.split(os.pathsep)

    if new_path not in current_path or \
       new_path + '\\' not in current_path:
        return
    
    if new_path + '\\' in current_path:
        new_path = new_path + '\\'
    
    current_path.remove(new_path)

    win32api.RegSetValueEx(key, "Path", 0, win32con.REG_EXPAND_SZ, os.pathsep.join(current_path))
    win32api.RegCloseKey(key)

    refresh_path()

def remove_from_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r+') as environment_variables_file:
        content = environment_variables_file.read()
        if f'export PATH="{new_path}{os.pathsep}$PATH"\n' in content:
            content = content.replace(f'export PATH="{new_path}{os.pathsep}$PATH"\n', '')
        if f'PATH="{new_path}{os.pathsep}$PATH"\n' in content:
            content = content.replace(f'PATH="{new_path}{os.pathsep}$PATH"\n', '')

    refresh_path()

def remove_from_path_bash(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile')):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile')
    elif os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.profile')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .bash_profile/.profile")

    remove_from_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def remove_from_path_sh(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.profile')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .profile")

    remove_from_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def remove_from_path_zsh(new_path):
    new_path = new_path.strip().replace('\\', '/').removesuffix('/')

    if os.path.expanduser('~/.zshenv'):
        file_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.zshenv')
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .zshenv")

    remove_from_environment_variables_file(file_path, new_path)

def remove_from_path_unix(shell):
    if shell == 'bash':
        return remove_from_path_bash
    elif shell == 'sh':
        return remove_from_path_sh
    elif shell == 'zsh':
        return remove_from_path_zsh

# ################################################################################

def refresh_path_win():
    key = win32api.RegOpenKeyEx(
        win32con.HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
        r"Environment",
        0,
        win32con.KEY_ALL_ACCESS
    )

    current_path, _ = win32api.RegQueryValueEx(key, "Path")

    os.environ['PATH'] = current_path

    win32api.RegCloseKey(key)

def refresh_from_environment_variables_file(shell, file_path):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
        [shell],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True
    )

    proc.stdin.write(f"source {file_path}\n")
    proc.stdin.write(f"echo $PATH\n")

    path, _ = proc.communicate()

    os.environ['PATH'] = path

def refresh_path_bash():
    if os.path.exists(os.path.expanduser('~/.bash_profile')):
        file_path = '~/.bash_profile'
    elif os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = '~/.profile'
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .bash_profile/.profile")

    refresh_from_environment_variables_file(shell, file_path)

def refresh_path_sh():
    if os.path.expanduser('~/.profile'):
        file_path = '~/.profile'
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .profile")

    refresh_from_environment_variables_file(shell, file_path)

def refresh_path_zsh():
    if os.path.expanduser('~/.zshenv'):
        file_path = '~/.zshenv'
    else:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Couldn't find the .zshenv")

    refresh_from_environment_variables_file(shell, file_path)

def refresh_path_unix(shell):
    if shell == 'bash':
        return refresh_path_bash
    elif shell == 'sh':
        return refresh_path_sh
    elif shell == 'zsh':
        return refresh_path_zsh

if sys.platform in ("win32", 'cygwin'):
    import win32api
    import win32con

    add_to_path = add_to_path_win
    remove_from_path = remove_from_path_win
    refresh_path = refresh_path_win
elif sys.platform.startswith("linux") or sys.platform == "darwin":
    shell = os.environ['SHELL'].removeprefix('/bin/')

    if shell in ('bash', 'sh', 'zsh'):
        add_to_path = add_to_path_unix(shell)
        remove_from_path = remove_from_path_unix(shell)
        refresh_path = refresh_path_unix(shell)
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"Unsupported shell: {shell}")
else:
    raise NotImplementedError(f"Unsupported platform: {sys.platform}")

I published this on PyPI in a package called pathenv, see https://github.com/foxypiratecove37350/pathenv for the source code.
Problems:

Windows: Probably some problems because of administrator privileges
Linux & macOS: remove_from_path() handles only two of the infinitely possible cases.

Improvements?

Add more shells than just ZSh, Bash, and Sh


You seem to want to impose a Windows-like experience on platforms where this will not be appreciated, or sometimes even possible.
The question originally asked about the system PATH, so there is one section here which addresses that.
System PATH
On many modern Unix-like systems, the system PATH is configured via files in /etc.

On systems with systemd, you can drop a file in /etc/environ.d which updates the system PATH.
On macOS, you can drop a file in /etc/paths.d

However, you usually should not.
See the Alternatives section below.
User PATH
There is no standard mechanism for this; but some installers like the one for rbenv will add a few lines to the user's shell configuration with a comment identifying which component added the change and why.
Unsurprisingly, this tends to produce bugs when users manually change the lines, or uninstall and then reinstall, or run the installer multiple times when something failed the first time, or they didn't understand what it did.
Like in the previous section, a less intrusive approach is to leave it to the user to install your software in a sane location in the first place, and simply document how they can amend their personal PATH if necessary.
Alternatives
The system administrator is responsible for maintaining the PATH and you don't want to sabotage their efforts. Simply install your binaries in /usr/local/bin (or if you are building e.g. a .deb package, in usr/bin in the package hierarchy) and let the user ensure that the PATH is sane.
If you insist on making your own installer, make it adhere to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard, which basically amounts to the same thing as far as binaries are concerned, but also contains detailed guidance for other files (shared configuration files, data files, libraries, etc).
A more fruitful approach is to provide packages for popular platforms (Debian packages will work on Ubuntu, Mint, etc; RPM for Red Hat, CentOS, Rocky etc; Alpine and Arch have their own systems, etc etc etc) and provide a .tar.gz with the usual configure; make; make install as a fallback (or perhaps in your case just a PyPI package?)
Package managers typically install everything system-wide, and do not even have a well-defined concept of a "current user". If nontrivial user configuration is necessary, perhaps package a separate tool which creates the necessary configuration files for each user who invokes it.
On Macs, if yours is an application bundle, that should be installed in /Applications; but for something which isn't a click-and-drool GUI, just fall back to traditional Unix conventions. There is no standard framework for this, but most users who have this need are probably already using Homebrew.
(There are competing package managers you could support as well; but this is emerging as the de facto standard.)
